# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected flatten_1 to have shape (2048,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to run this code, and I have this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected flatten_4 to have shape (2048,) but got array with shape (2,)

```
NUM_CLASSES = 2
CHANNELS = 3
IMAGE_RESIZE = 224
RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE = 'avg'
DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION = 'softmax'
OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION = 'categorical_crossentropy'
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 3
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING = 10
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION = 10
BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING = 100
BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION = 100
BATCH_SIZE_TESTING = 1
resnet_weights_path = '../input/resnet50/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
model = Sequential()
train_data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
model.layers.pop() 
model = Model(input=model.input,output=model.layers[-1].output)
model.summary()
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9), metrics=  ['binary_accuracy'])
data_dir = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\RESNET"
batch_size = 32
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
image_size = IMAGE_RESIZE
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
def append_ext(fn):
    return fn+".jpg"
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
train_dir_path = dir_path + '\data'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(dir_path) if isfile(join(dir_path, f))]
data_labels = [0, 1]
t = []
maxi = 25145
LieOffset = 15799
i = 0
while i < maxi: # t = tuple
if i <= LieOffset:
    t.append(label['Lie'])
else:
    t.append(label['Truth'])
i = i+1
train_datagenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        validation_split=0.2) 
train_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False, subset='training')
validation_generator = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir, # same directory as training data kifkif
        target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
        class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False, subset='validation') 
(BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING, len(train_generator), BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION, len(validation_generator))
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss',    save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
from sklearn.grid_search import ParameterGrid
param_grid = {'epochs': [5, 10, 15], 'steps_per_epoch' : [10, 20, 50]}
grid = ParameterGrid(param_grid)
val_loss as final model
for params in grid:
    print(params)
fit_history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
        epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
        callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper])
model.load_weights("../working/best.hdf5")
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. Copy and paste it into your question, then select it and press Ctrl+K to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that your models output layer should have 2 nodes whereas you have 2048 as you are using the output of `avg_pool` layer of ResNet50 model as your model output. So, you can add a Dense layer having 2 nodes on top of the `avg_pool` layer to solve the problem.

```
model = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
print(model.summary())
x = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
predictions = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions)
print(model.summary())
```

As I'm not quite sure about what type of problem you are solving, i assumed that multilabel (2) classification as your data label shape is (2,).

However, if you are solving a binary classification problem then you need to change your label so that it's either 1 or 0. So, Change `class_mode='categorical'` to `class_mode='binary'` in both `train_generator` and `validation_generator`. In that case the model output layer should have `1` node.

```
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am doing a binary classification and If I add : x = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
predictions = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(input = model.input, output = predictions) as you suggest It dosn't work. I still stuck ... Thanks again